# Powershell/cmd to search content of all c$ hidden shares

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Using "net view" I can view all the pcs on the network and browse their hidden shares \PC_NAME\c$ . But I can't find an easy way to search every pc on the network at once.

Is there a way using cmd/powershell to search for .pst .ost files on every machine in the network? 
I want to use powershell or command prompt to automate it every few weeks.

Comment: Why not use group policy, logon script or some other management technique to manage Outlook's local data files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential UsernameWithAccess
$servers = @("server1","server2")
foreach ($sever in $servers){
    $shares = Get-WmiObject Win32_share -computer netdb -Credential $credentials
    foreach ($path in $shares.name){
        $content = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\netdb\$path
        $List = $content | where {$_.extension -eq ".dll"}
        $List | format-table name
    } 
}
```

Make sure you change UsernamewithAccess with your user and servernames in second line, and extention from .dll to what you need to search for.